# Query documents in firestore from an array of ID's

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I was wondering how I can query documents from a firestore collection from an array of ID's? I only want the documents in the collection that are in the array of ID's. I looked at another answer and think my approach is correct, however, I am getting an error.

```
(node:15105) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>      at /Users/username/SideProjects/projectname/functions/index.js:40:38
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

The error happens because the function is not finding any documents in the collection from that array of ID's. However, I double-checked the database and know that there are documents in the collection with ID's from the array.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

....

let feedItems = db.collection(feedItemsCollection)

feedItemsList = feedItems.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ['HPOorsSnbHpTYwwXxfWw']).get().then(snapshot2 => {
       console.log(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
       console.log("In feed Items")
       //console.log(feedItemIds)
       console.log(snapshot2[0])

       //error happens on this line because snapshot2[0] returns undefined
       console.log(snapshot2[0].data())
})
```

Snapshot2[0] returns undefined which I'm assuming means that no data was returned. I think I'm not properly calling documentId(), but don't know the fix.

Comment: `snapshot2` is not an array, so you can't index into it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There "maybe" two problems with your code. Follow both points to make sure things are working

1. **Data inside `snapshot2` maybe `empty`**

You'll first have to fix your code to test this theory. You're not accessing data from `snapshot2` correctly. To do it right, one way is this:

```
// `snapshot2` will have a `docs` property that you can leverage
const snapshot2Data = snapshot2.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
```

2. **`.documentId()` may not be doing what it's supposed to (as you said)**

To test this theory, check if `snapshot2Data` is empty. Run :

```
console.log(snapshot2Data); // what do you get ?
```

If no, it's not empty and you got data back, then you're all set. Nothing more to do

If yes, it is empty, then run :

```
console.log(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()); // what do you get ?
```

Did you get back a `string`? If no, then we have another problem. You'll need to take a closer look at your `firebase-admin` setup, as well.