# Get specific documents that are stored in an array of ID's from a collection in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get specific documents from a collection in firestore.
The document ids are stored in the `array` variable

I Tried two different methods from the following thread in github:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/990#issuecomment-605941438

First method using `.getAll`:

```
import { getApp } from "@firebase/app"
import { getFirestore, collection} from "@firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore(getApp())
const refs = array.map(item => doc(db, `collection/document/collection`, item))
const res = await db.getAll(...refs)
```

I received the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: db.getAll is not a function
```

Second method using: `FieldPath.documentId`

```
import { getApp } from "@firebase/app"
import { getFirestore, collection, FieldPath} from "@firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore(getApp())
const ref = collection(db, `collection/document/collection`))
const q = query(ref, where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', array));
```

but again I received a different error:

```
FieldPath.documentId is not a function
```

I also found the following thread on stackoverflow:
[Query documents in firestore from an array of ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68870821/query-documents-in-firestore-from-an-array-of-ids)
But there was no good answer

Answer (score 0):

You're using the newer modular syntax of the v9 and later SDKs, where `documentId` is a top-level function. See its [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#documentid).